# C# Adding Derived classes to a collection of Base classes

Tags: c#, collections

```
  public abstract class Person
   {
      protected string name;

       public Person(string firstName)
      {
         name = firstName;
      }
   {

public BusinessPerson : Person
{
public BusinessPerson(string newName) : base(newName)
      {
      }
}

public class Group : CollectionBase
   {
      public void Add(Person newPerson)
      {
         List.Add(newPerson);
      }
   }

int Main 
{
    Group VariousPeople = new Group();
    VariousPeople.Add(new BusinessPerson("Jack")); // says invalid arguments
}
```

================================================================================

If I am correct shouldn't polymorphism allow me to store derived types in a container of
base types? Why doesn't this work for me?

Comment: That code (with the obvious syntax errors fixed) workes just fine on my box

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. Your code in the question is missing some braces and things, but once fixed, it compiles and works fine on my compiler. Fixed code is below.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Group VariousPeople = new Group();
        VariousPeople.Add(new BusinessPerson("Jack"));
    }
}

public abstract class Person
{
    protected string name;

    public Person(string firstName)
    {
        name = firstName;
    }
}

public class BusinessPerson : Person
{
    public BusinessPerson(string newName)
        : base(newName)
    {

    }
}

public class Group : CollectionBase
{
    public void Add(Person newPerson)
    {
        List.Add(newPerson);
    }
}
```